# Não consigo clicar no alerta utilizando selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Ao clicar num botão, um alerta é emitido pedindo para eu confirmar, acontece que já tentei usar o Pynput para confirmar com o Key.press do ENTER. Mas não funcionou. O alerta está em outra janela, então o selenium não o vê

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao inspecionar o botão, tem um código HREF com um outro link, que não consigo clicar diretamente nele. Então a solução seria passar com um ENTER, mas não consegui com o PYNPUT, alguma ideia? Meu código abaixo

```
browser = Chrome()

wdw = WebDriverWait(browser,10)
browser.get('https://sso.acesso.gov.br/login?client_id=cav.receita.fazenda.gov.br')

browser.implicitly_wait(15)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login-dados-certificado"]/p[2]/a/img').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cert-digital"]/a').click()

wdw.until(
    new_window_is_opened(browser.window_handles)
)

browser.switch_to_window(
    browser.window_handles[-1]
)

browser.switch_to_alert
```

Answer (score -2):

é só usar a biblioteca pyautogui maninho,
exemplo
tipo faz ele movimentar o mouse e clicar no aviso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Você colocou uma imagem do código. Apesar de parecer uma boa ideia, não é! Um dos motivos é que para o autor da pergunta testar ele não pode copiar o código e alterar algo dentro. Clique no link editar e coloque o código/erro como texto.